# Why visual Studio want specific version of sqlserver.types?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have an application that uses `Microsoft.SQLServer.Types`.
I added the reference to project. Version of library is `13.0.0.0` but application can't start with error

> "Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version =
>   10.0.0.0".

Why does it trying to load this version of library and how to change this behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely one of the other libs you are referencing in your project is dependent on the lower version of `Microsoft.SQLServer.Types`. (In your case 10.0.0.0). You can try to update other references to the latest version where a newer `Microsoft.SQLServer.Types` library is used, that might resolve your issue.

Comment: How to detect which reference should be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason why you will be getting this error is that another assembly that your project is referencing a version `10.0.0.0` of `Microsoft.SQLServer.Types`. With your project referencing version `13.0.0.0`, the other assembly which is dependent on version `10.0.0.0` can no longer find the correct version it needs since version `13.0.0.0` is deployed with your project.

If this is the case, you have two option to fix this:

1. Reference version `10.0.0.0` in your project instead.
2. Add an [assembly binding redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) to your web.config/app.config.

For your case, the binding redirect configuration would look something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>  
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SQLServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your advice is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

May be in your solution project (csproj file) or the web/app.config is still referencing version 10.0.0.0.

try by installing using pakage manager console

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

Comment: It didn't help. Nuget installs version Microsoft.SQLServer.Types 11.0.0.0 not 10.